# Neville's method is used to approximate $f(0.4)$. Determine $P_2=f(0.5)$

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

I'm given a partial table from which to work:

$x_0=0$      $P_0=1$

$x_1=0.25$   $P_1=2$     $P_{0,1}=2.6$

$x_2=0.5$    $P_2= $     $P_{1,2}= $     $P_{0,1,2}=$

$x_3=0.75$   $P_3=8$     $P_{2,3}=2.4$   $P_{1,2,3}=2.96$   $P_{1,2,3,4}=3.016$

I'm thinking I can find it recursively by

$P_{2,3}= \dfrac{(x-x_2)P_3-(x-x_3)P_2}{x_3-x_2}$ and solving for $P_2$

I got:

$2.4=\dfrac{(0.4-0.5)*8-(0.4-0.75)P_2}{(.75-.5)}$

And got $P_2=4$. The answer given in the back of the book is $4$.

So I think I did it right.

Thanks!

Comment: @Moo yes I am. I just don't know how to format the table, but the problem is stated exactly as it is in the book. Thanks.

Comment: @Moo, in other words, the values of $P_2, P_{1,2}, P_{0,1,2}$ are not given. I have to find $P_2$ Recursively using Neville's method.